# Mudar valor do input com javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um campo para inserir notas e gostaria que se o valor inserido fosse maior que 10 ou menor que 0 o valor fosse apagado do input.

Tentei fazer com o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso.

```js
function verifica(v){
  if (v > 10 || v < 0){
   v = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="verifica(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passe `this` como argumento do `onchange` e altere o método para trabalhar com o elemento e não apenas o valor.

Assim você pode alterar a propriedade `value`.

```js
function verifica(el){
  if (el.value > 10 || el.value < 0){
    el.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="verifica(this)">
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.